# How to get values in a grouped Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

dataframe as below this come after reading a Table in a word document

```
0   Occupational Therapy (66)       Nan         
1        - avg Age                <Sheet1_1_0>  
2        - Avg.Visits             <Sheet1_2_0>  
3   Physiotherapists (72)               Nan 
4        - avg Age                <Sheet1_4_0>  
5        - Avg.Visits             <Sheet1_5_0>  
6   Social workers (89)                 Nan
7        - avg Age                <Sheet1_7_0>  
8        - Avg.Visits             <Sheet1_7_0>
```

desired output

```
0    Occupational Therapy (66)       - avg Age                <Sheet1_1_0> 
1    Occupational Therapy (66)       - Avg.Visits             <Sheet1_2_0>  
2    Physiotherapists (72)           - avg Age                <Sheet1_4_0>  
3    Physiotherapists (72)           - Avg.Visits             <Sheet1_5_0>  
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `NaN` columns as a check to create a `work_type` column.

assuming you don't have headers.

```
print(df)

                           0             1
0  Occupational Therapy (66)           NaN
1                  - avg Age  <Sheet1_1_0>
2               - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_2_0>
3      Physiotherapists (72)           NaN
4                  - avg Age  <Sheet1_4_0>
5               - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_5_0>
6        Social workers (89)           NaN
7                  - avg Age  <Sheet1_7_0>
8               - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_7_0>
```

---

```
# df = df.replace('Nan',np.nan,regex=True)
df.loc[df[1].isna(), 'work_type'] = df[0]
df1 = df.assign(work_type=df['work_type'].ffill()).dropna(subset=[1])

print(df1[['work_type',0,1]])

       work_type             0             1
1  Occupational Therapy (66)     - avg Age  <Sheet1_1_0>
2  Occupational Therapy (66)  - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_2_0>
4      Physiotherapists (72)     - avg Age  <Sheet1_4_0>
5      Physiotherapists (72)  - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_5_0>
7        Social workers (89)     - avg Age  <Sheet1_7_0>
8        Social workers (89)  - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_7_0>
```